# EclipseLink JPA with App Engine: cache synchronization

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, caching, eclipselink

I have an App Engine project which persists the data inside a Cloud SQL instance, using EclipseLink as JPA persistence manager.

Due to the nature of App Engine (multi-instance environment) we have some concerns on how to synchronize the JPA cache between the instances.

Each JPA instance runs inside a single App Engine instances, so the Memcache service of App Engine is not used (else, EclipseLink does not "know" of what App Engine memcache is or how to use it)

Here is a simple scenario example:

```
- Instance A read object 1: value="A"
- Instance B read object 1: value="A"

- Instance A write object 1: value="B"
- JPA cache of Instance A is evicted due to write operation

- Instance A read object 1: value="B" (the value is retrieved from the database because cache has been evicted after write operation)
- Instance B read object 1: value="A" (no write operation has been performed, the cache is still valid so the value has not been updated)
```

Searching around for this kind of Behaviour I found different articles which talk about this [1] [2] [3] [4].

I quote:

> unless the database is modified directly by other applications, or by
>   the same application on other servers in a clustered environment

As the nature of App Engine, for this we can consider it as "*other servers in a clustered environment*", so the case seems to be the one.

Of course the proper way on how to handle this problem should be build a cache layer for JPA which is built on top of App Engine memcache service, but from my searches I understand that EclipseLink does not allow developing a custom cache layer.
I'm available to build something which can bridge between EclipseLink and App Engine memcache, but I cannot find any reference if there are the proper "hooks" on how to do it.

From the documentation there are few suggestions on how to handle this:

- *disable the shared cache*: This is not a suitable option due to lose of application performance
- *using a distributed cache (such as Oracle TopLink Grid with Oracle Coherence)*: 
  I would like to use the App Engine memcache service, but as I understand there is no EclipseLink "hook" that we can use
- *using cache coordination (synchronizing the caches, as discussed in this example)*
  The provided methos seems to be not usable with App Engine environment

Is there a known solution on how properly handle this cache scenario?
The scenario here is very clear, when a write operation is made inside an instance, all the existing JPA cache need to be "notified" as well to evict their own cache.

[1] https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/CacheCoordination

[2] http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/cache011.htm

[3] https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Coordination

[4] https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching#Caching_in_Clustered_Environments

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the EclipseLink (EL) source to see if there is any easy way to extend the cache coordination mechanism to work with GAE.

EL support JMS, and RMI by default, and the cache coordination is built around remoting, so EL can send commands (`org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.coordination.Command`), which are executed against the `AbstractSession`on every host in the cluster.

I don't think there is any way you could use MemCache for caching, because the commands, like `MergeChangeSetCommand` always operate on the `AbstractSession`.

It is possible to build your own cache coordination protocol, this is done by extending `org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.coordination.TransportManager`, and setting `eclipselink.cache.coordination.protocol=com.example.MyTransportManager`, but the `DiscoveryManager` uses multicast which is typically not available in the cloud. If you could discover all your GAE instances (and send data directly to each node), I think it would be possible to create a http based cache coordination solution. On AWS it is possible to ask the load balancer for the list of nodes, this is how we get around the multicast problem when we need to use Hazelcast, for intra node communication.

Comment: `If you could discover all your GAE instances` 
In App Engine this is possibile only using basic or manual scaling, instances in automatic scaling can't be addressed directly.
You can read from the documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/an-overview-of-app-engine#scaling_types_and_instance_classes) `Instances are anonymous.`. I'm looking a way to directly implement the App Engine Memcache Service which is already a synchronized service

Comment: As I write, I'm fairly sure you can't use MemCache as second level cache for EclipseLink. JPA is part of the JavaEE spec, and it is not really designed for Cloud. I think your only options is to disable shared caching, and do some custom caching for stuff you access often - That what we normally do.